# Problem with almost sure converges random variable with Bernoulli distribution.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let's define
$$P(X_n)=\begin{cases}1,&w.p=\; \frac1n \\0,&w.p = 1-\frac1n\end{cases}$$
I want to show that does not exist X such that : 
${\displaystyle {\overset {}{X_{n}\,{\xrightarrow {\mathrm {a.s.} }}\,X.}}}$

We know that 
$$
X_{n} \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} X
\iff \mathbb{P}\left(\omega:\lim_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\right)=1. 
$$

Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: You've asked several questions related to the same problem without any real thoughts of your own.

Comment: Proof by contradiction is always a good place to start when you want to prove something doesen't exist.

Comment: What does it mean $P(X_n)=1$ with probability $p=\frac1n$?

Comment: $P(X_n=1)=\frac1n$

Answer (score 3):

This is  false. On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $X_n =I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied but $X_n$ does tend to $0$ almost surely.

However, if $X_n$'s are independent then the statement is true. $\sum P(X_n=0) =\infty$ and $\sum P(X_n=1) =\infty$. By Borel Cantelli Lemma we see that $X_n$ oscillates with probbaility $1$.